# Listen to attribute changes in a backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'd like to call a method in my view when its `attributes` property is updated. The following code gives me an error: `undefined is not a function`.

```
SimpleView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function(){
        this.attributes = _.extend(this.attributes, Backbone.Events); // update
        this.attributes.on('change', this.updateAttributes(), this);
    }

});
```

How can I elegantly bind an event listener to the attributes?

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4K7X/2/)

**UPDATE:** I figured I have to extend `attributes` with `Backbone.Events` so I can listen to changes. Yeah... So now I don't get anymore errors, but still nothing happens. Any help would be largely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to listen to the attributes of the view or is the model what you refer to?

Comment: Absolutely certain. I'm referring to the attributes that will be added to the html tag of this view (in my case 'data-type').

Comment: So for example, you can re-render the view every time the attributes of the model change `this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render, this);`

Comment: That would be great, but the view attributes are set independently from the model attributes. I was under the impression the on() method worked on any object. Do you know why it doesn't work in this case?

Comment: In this case you are trying to use the function `on` in the `attributes` property of the view that is not defined and therefore throwing the error **undefined is not a function**.

Comment: Could you post the entire code of your view and your template? So I can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No problem, I just added a JSFiddle to my question.

Comment: I can only think of another model holding the data-type, so you can listen to the change in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would recommend you to use a model for holding the attributes, if you want to stay with your current approach, you need to manually trigger the event.

```
this.attributes.trigger('change');
```

I have updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Puigcerber/Z4K7X/3/) so you can get an idea of how it works.